# DICOM [Storage SCP] : What should be the Associate Response if no proposed presentation context is accepted?

Tags: dicom

My application is Storage SCP. Third party Storage SCU connects to my application and proposes two presentation contexts. SCP does not support either. What Associate Response should I send in this case?

1. Set the status of each presentation context to "Rejected - Abstract syntax not supported.", and send Associate Accept. This way, none of the presentation contexts in Associate Response will be accepted. Associate Accept does not make sense here.
2. Send Associate Reject all together.

I am doing option 2 now, but not sure if this is correct implementation. I searched specifications but could not found anything conclusive. Please mention the location in specifications that clearly discuss about this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no explicit rule, but I think it is very clear implicitly by the reasons that the SCP must give for association- and/or presentation context rejection.

Referring to PS 3.8, 7.1.1.9, there is a positive list of valid reasons for association rejection. There is no reason defined which is suitable to indicate that the association is rejected because none of the proposed presentation contexts can be accepted.

For Presentation Context rejection, PS3.8, table 9-18 defines the possible reasons. I suppose that either

```
3 - abstract-syntax-not-supported (provider rejection)
```

or

```
4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported (provider rejection)
```

Is appropriate to express the reason for rejection. In other words, I do not think that your implementation is correct. You should accept the association, reject all presentation contexts and expect the SCU to release / abort the association.